# How to use webmock to simulate a request?

Tags: ruby, rspec, webmock

My app create a github gist using API. I need to simulate a request to the API with rspec. I'm using the webmock gem but I don't quite understand how to use it for my application. I need a little help to get started.

This is my ***spec/Git_Request_spec.rb***

```
require_relative '../Gist_Request.rb'
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe GistRequest do
  describe "#post" do
    it "crear gist" do
      filename = "test.txt"
      description = "descripción"
      state = true
      content = "contenido"

      gist_create = GistRequest.new(description, state, filename, content)
      gist_create.post()

      expect(gist_create.response_status).to eq "201"
    end

    it "campos no válidos" do
      filename = "test.txt"
      description = "descripción"
      state = true
      content = "contenido"

      gist_create = GistRequest.new(filename, content, state, description)
      gist_create.post()

      expect(gist_create.response_status).to eq "422"
   end
 end
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Once you have called `Webmock.enable!` (see https://github.com/bblimke/webmock), whenever you make a request from your test Webmock will cause it to error, and will out instructions for how to mock that request.

Comment: Should I call him in Gist_Request_spec.rb?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the method **[stub_request](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby#accessing-a-response-object)** to simulate your interaction with api

```
stub_request(:http_method, url).with(`your data in 
request`).to_return(`what do you expect to receive in response`).
```

Comment: Like this? ```stub_request(:http_method, url).with(gist_create.response_status).to_return("201")``` that didnt work for me: ```WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError:
       Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: POST .......```